# How can I create a multi-boot USB using livecd-tools?

Tags: boot, livecd, fedora

While going through the man page, I found some options that seem to suggest that the command line tool `livecd-iso-to-disk` is capable of creating a multiple-boot USB:

```
--multi
    Used when installing multiple image copies to signal configuration of
    the boot files for the image in the --livedir <dir> parameter.

--livedir <dir>
    Used with multiple image installations to designate the directory <dir>
    for the particular image.
```

I have a 32 bit ISO image file and a 64 bit one in the directory `/var/Installers/Fedora-20`. I would like to be able to select either one from the grub menu when booting from the USB. I tried running the following:

```
# livecd-iso-to-disk --efi --multi --livedir /var/Installers/Fedora-20 /dev/sdc1
```

But it didn't work because the `<source>` argument is missing. I have two ISO images, it seems counter-intuitive to ask for the `<source>` when the directory to the image files is provided. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with this tool but from looking at the source for the `livecd-iso-to-disk.sh` script [here](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/livecd/tree/tools/livecd-iso-to-disk.sh), I think you've got this backwards. You still need to provide a *single* source (not a directory) because this tool can only do one ISO at a time, so you need to run it once for every ISO you want to add. Meanwhile, `--livedir` is supposed to be the name for the *destination* directory. This is so the tool does not use the default directory and clobber the last ISO you installed.

If I had to guess as to the correct usage based on what I have read, I would try

```
livecd-iso-to-disk --efi --multi --livedir <name_for_32_bit_dir> /var/Installers/Fedora-20/<name_of_32_bit.iso> /dev/sdc1
livecd-iso-to-disk --efi --multi --livedir <name_for_64_bit_dir> /var/Installers/Fedora-20/<name_of_64_bit.iso> /dev/sdc1
```

More information: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB#litd

---

Notice how the description of `--livedir` says "for the particular image", which implies singular, not a directory of multiple images.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. I manage to get the 64bit ISO file in. But the 32bit one complains that it does not support EFI booting. After removing the `--efi` flag, it gives an error saying that the partition isn't marked bootable despite having the bootable flag set. Should I accept your answer and post this as a separate question?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Since it sounds like a separate issue it is better to have it in separate question I think. Perhaps the question here is how to mix efi and non-efi isos on the same USB. It is probably easier to go non-EFI for the entire USB drive.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will try figure it out myself first by editing the grub config and pointing it to the 32 bit ISO file.